# I'm getting an image URL from a callback and I can successfully display it, but I cannot send it to the page I am loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, instagram-api

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next)=> {
  let instaPost;

  getLatest(callback => {
    instaPost = callback;
    console.log(instaPost);

  });

  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home',
    insta: instaPost
  });
});

function getLatest(callback) {
  axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=xxx&count=1')
    .then(response => {
      callback((response.data.data[0].link));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      callback(error);
    });

}



module.exports = router;
```

the console.log(instaPost); successfully returns the url I want, however, when I try to send it to the page inside res.render, nothing gets across, please could someone help me to understand why.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Call `res.render(...)` inside the `getLatest()` callback function.

Given the current code, `res.render()` is executed prior to the `insta` property being set.

Answer (score 0):

`Axios` works with promises so the most convenient thing is to keep that form of work, the `GET` method is asynchronous with the following way you can get the value you need.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    getLatest().then((instaPost) => {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Home',
            insta: instaPost
        });
    });
});

function getLatest() {
    return axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=xxx&count=1')
        .then(response => {
            return Promise.resolve(response.data.data[0].link);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}



module.exports = router;
```

> If you do not know how the promises work, I leave this link so you can
>   read and understand.
>   [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thank you! I realised I could do the whole api call inside the router.get without having to define a callback :)

Comment: @HenryPenton Yes, you can do that and take advantage of the function that provides axios but for maintenance and a more orderly development having the code separated in functions and classes are good code practices.

Comment: @HenryPenton If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.